# How to search a binary file for a signature offset

Tags: python, memory, io, mmap, binary-data

This is my example so far:

```py
import io
import mmap
import os
import time

# 20 MB test file
filename = "random.bin"
if not os.path.isfile(filename):
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        for _ in range(20):
            f.write(os.urandom(1_000_000))

signature = b"\x01\x02\x03\x04"

print("Method 1:")
start_time = time.time()
offsets = []
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    buf = b"\x00" + f.read(len(signature) - 1)
    for offset, byte in enumerate(iter(lambda: f.read(1), b"")):
        buf = buf[1:] + byte
        if buf == signature:
            offsets.append(offset)
print(f"{time.time() - start_time:.2f} seconds")
print(offsets)

print("Method 2:")
start_time = time.time()
offsets = []
with open(filename, "rb") as f, mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as mm:
    for offset in range(len(mm)):
        if mm[offset : offset + len(signature)] == signature:
            offsets.append(offset)
print(f"{time.time() - start_time:.2f} seconds")
print(offsets)

print("Method 3:")
start_time = time.time()
offsets = []
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    offset = 0
    chunk = f.read(len(signature) - 1)
    while True:
        chunk = chunk[-(len(signature) - 1) :] + f.read1(io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
        if len(chunk) < len(signature):
            # EOF
            break
        for i in range(len(chunk) - (len(signature) - 1)):
            if chunk[i : i + len(signature)] == signature:
                offsets.append(offset + i)
        offset += len(chunk) - (len(signature) - 1)
print(f"{time.time() - start_time:.2f} seconds")
print(offsets)
```

I'm searching through a 20 MB test file, looking for `signature` of 4 bytes. Switching to method 2 with `mmap.mmap` saved 50% of runtime, but it's still really slow. Especially since my actual target file will be between 1 and 10 GB. (Which is why I don't just load the whole file into memory, first.) It is orders of magnitude slower than `md5sum random.bin`.

Edit: I've added another method, which doesn't use `f.read(1)`, but reads chunks of `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE` and also uses `read1` to prevent any blocking. But it's still not faster.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the file wasn't the issue. Using chunks instead of `read(1)` should definitely be fast enough. However, afterwards, it's apparently a bad idea to iterate the bytes with slicing. [`bytes.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.find) is *much* faster. I don't yet understand why, but I've posted a new question [How is str.find so fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72080976/how-is-str-find-so-fast) about that.

Here is a simple solution - a 4th method for the example code from above - which uses `bytes.find`:

```py
print("Method 4:")
start_time = time.time()
offsets = []
def _find(haystack, needle, start=0, offset=0):
    while True:
        position = haystack.find(needle, start)
        if position < 0:
            return
        start = position + 1
        yield position + offset
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    offset = 0
    chunk = f.read(len(signature) - 1)
    while True:
        chunk = chunk[-(len(signature) - 1) :] + f.read1(io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
        if len(chunk) < len(signature):
            # EOF
            break
        offsets.extend(_find(chunk, signature, offset=offset))
        offset += len(chunk) - (len(signature) - 1)
print(f"{time.time() - start_time:.2f} seconds")
print(offsets)
```

It produces the following time measurements:

```
Method 1:
8.83 seconds
[20971596, 20971686]
Method 2:
5.69 seconds
[20971596, 20971686]
Method 3:
5.76 seconds
[20971596, 20971686]
Method 4:
0.02 seconds
[20971596, 20971686]
```

So yeah, method 4 is clearly the winner.