# How is str.find so fast?

Tags: python, string, optimization, find, substring

I had an earlier problem where I was looking for a substring while iterating the string and using slicing. Turns out that's a *really* bad idea regarding performance. `str.find` is much faster. But I don't understand why?

```py
import random
import string
import timeit

# Generate 1 MB of random string data
haystack = "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=1_000_000))

def f():
    return [i for i in range(len(haystack)) if haystack[i : i + len(needle)] == needle]

def g():
    return [i for i in range(len(haystack)) if haystack.startswith(needle, i)]

def h():
    def find(start=0):
        while True:
            position = haystack.find(needle, start)
            if position < 0:
                return
            start = position + 1
            yield position
    return list(find())

number = 100
needle = "abcd"
expectation = f()
for func in "fgh":
    assert eval(func + "()") == expectation
    t = timeit.timeit(func + "()", globals=globals(), number=number)
    print(func, t)
```

Results:

```
f 26.46937609199813
g 16.11952730899793
h 0.07721933699940564
```

Comment: Slicing is allocating lots of new strings. `str.find()` can just refer to substrings within the original string data, without allocating any extra memory.

Answer (score 1):

`f` and `g` are slow since they check if `needle` can be found in every possible location of `haystack` resulting in a `O(n m)` complexity. `f` is slower because of the slicing operation that creates a new string object (as pointed out by Barmar in the comments).

`h` is fast because it can skip many locations. For example, if the `needle` string is not found, only one `find` is performed. The built-in `find` function is highly optimized in C and thus faster than an interpreted pure-Python code. Additionally, the `find` function use an efficient algorithm called [Crochemore and Perrin's Two-Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-way_string-matching_algorithm). This algorithm is much faster than searching `needle` at every possible location of `haystack` when the string is relatively big. The related CPython code is available [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h).

If the number of occurrence is relatively small, your implementation should already be good. Otherwise, it may be better to use a custom variant based on the CPTW algorithm of possibly the [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) but doing that in pure-Python will be very inefficient. You could do that in C or with Cython. That being said this is not trivial to do and not great to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in Python functions are implemented in C, which allows them to be much faster. It's not possible to make a function that performs just as well when using Python.